# React child component state management

Tags: reactjs

I´ve been reading about different ways of managing state from child components but I´m still a little confused if my workflow is correct or if it´s an anti-pattern.

Basically I have a component with material-ui sibling components and those component´s props need to be update as their state changes. Is there a better way of managing child components state ?

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SearchTicket.css';


class SearchTicket extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      txtSearchTicket: {
        errorText: null,
        value: '',
        hintText: 'Número do chamado',
      },
      btnSearch: {
        label: 'Buscar',
        disabled: false,
      },
    };

    this.handleTxtSearchTicket = this.handleTxtSearchTicket.bind(this);
    this.searchTicket = this.searchTicket.bind(this);
    this.isTicketValid = this.isTicketValid.bind(this);
  }

  handleTxtSearchTicket(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const newState = prevState;
      newState.txtSearchTicket.value = value;
      return newState;
    });
  }

  isTicketValid() {
    const re = new RegExp(/^(im|sd|[0-9])[0-9]+/, 'i');
    if (re.test(this.state.txtSearchTicket.value)) {
      return true;
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const newState = prevState;
      newState.txtSearchTicket.value = '';
      newState.txtSearchTicket.errorText = 'Número de chamado inválido';
      return newState;
    });
  }

  searchTicket() {
    if (this.isTicketValid()) {
      console.log(`Fetching call ${this.state.txtSearchTicket.value}`);
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        const newState = prevState;
        newState.btnSearch.disabled = !newState.btnSearch.disabled;
        return newState;
      });
    }
    // TODO: implement retrieve call from api
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      margin: 15,
      width: 180,
      heigh: 40,
    };

    return (
      <form>
        <TextField
          name="txtSearchTicket"
          hintText={this.state.txtSearchTicket.hintText}
          floatingLabelText={this.state.txtSearchTicket.hintText}
          errorText={this.state.txtSearchTicket.errorText}
          onChange={this.handleTxtSearchTicket}
          value={this.state.txtSearchTicket.value}
        />
        <br />
        <RaisedButton
          name="btnSearch"
          label={this.state.btnSearch.label}
          disabled={this.state.btnSearch.disabled}
          onClick={() => this.searchTicket()}
          style={style}
          primary
        />
      </form>
    );
    // <RaisedButton label="Buscar" style={style} primary={true}/>
  }
}
```

Comment: You're only showing one component right now. what do you mean by child state?

Comment: Also, without any other code, what you're doing right now is exactly right, since there *is no child state*. the state lives in the parent

Comment: `TextField` and  `RaisedButton` are child components of  `SearchTicket ` right ? Every time an onChange event is triggered on the `TextField` a function is triggered on `SearchTicket` and `TextField` is re-rendered accordingly. With what I´m not sure is if this is a manintainable and prefereble way of doing it.

Comment: What other ways are you considering?

Comment: there's a page about this in the react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: It just seem as a lot of repetitive code, with all those `setState ` calls. I´ll check link you provided. Thanks :)